# Formatting a Custom Sidebar dimensions to avoid clipping

Tags: beamer, formatting

I'm trying to create a custom sidebar to have in parts of my presentation, and would like to get some help sorting out some of the problems I've encountered.

First, the yellow box there is where the 'Step 1' text is located for this document. I don't want it to be hidden, so how would I adjust the sidebar's height to start lower than the top bar to avoid this clipping?

A solution to this has been pointed out in the comments:

> To get the first step down try \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{% \vspace*{\headheight}% Step 1 ... – samcarter

If though there is a way to define the actual object rather than shifting down the text within the object, this would be preferable.

Second, I would like to clean up the formatting of the sidebar so that you don't have the pixels cut the way they are along the location of the frame title (blue band) and the top navigation bar. I do want to keep both of these other features.

Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

And the code for how I got this:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.75cm}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar left}{bg=black, fg=green}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
    \vfill
    Step 1
    \vfill
    Step 2
    \vfill
    Step 3
    \vfill
    Step 4
    \vfill
    Step 5
    \vfill
    Step 6
    \vfill
    Step 7
    \vfill
    Step 8
    \vfill
    Step 9
    \vfill
    Step 10
    \vfill
    Step 11
    \vfill
    Step 12
    \vfill
    Step 13
    \vfill
    Step 14
    \vfill
    Step 15
    \vfill
    Step 16
    \vfill
    Step 17
    \vfill
    Step 18
    \vfill
    Step 19
    \vfill
    Step 20
    \vfill
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Section 2.1}
\subsubsection{Section 2.1.1}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part A}
    This would be the start to the problem
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part B}
    This would start the solution
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part C}
    This would have the next step
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part D}
    This next step process would continue here (and to further slides if needed)
\end{frame}

\subsection{Section 2.2}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.2.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.2.2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To get the first step down try `\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
 \vspace*{\headheight}%
 Step 1 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two warnings:

1. For frames without `frametitle` the shading below the headline is lost, because I redefined it to go the background colour of the side bar
2. Still present: "pixels cut along the location of the frame title" - I'm not sure, this is real or a viewer issue.

---

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \colorlet{global.bg}{bg}
    \usebeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{frametitle}
    \usebeamercolor{sidebar left}

    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
        color(0ex)=(sidebar left.bg);%
        color(3ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
    }    
  }
\makeatother

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.75cm}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar left}{bg=black, fg=green}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
    \vspace{\headheight}
    Step 1
    \vfill
    Step 2
    \vfill
    Step 3
    \vfill
    Step 4
    \vfill
    Step 5
    \vfill
    Step 6
    \vfill
    Step 7
    \vfill
    Step 8
    \vfill
    Step 9
    \vfill
    Step 10
    \vfill
    Step 11
    \vfill
    Step 12
    \vfill
    Step 13
    \vfill
    Step 14
    \vfill
    Step 15
    \vfill
    Step 16
    \vfill
    Step 17
    \vfill
    Step 18
    \vfill
    Step 19
    \vfill
    Step 20
    \vfill
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Section 2.1}
\subsubsection{Section 2.1.1}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part A}
    This would be the start to the problem
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part B}
    This would start the solution
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part C}
    This would have the next step
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.1.1 part D}
    This next step process would continue here (and to further slides if needed)
\end{frame}

\subsection{Section 2.2}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.2.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{2.2.2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to maintain the font size in the main body of the slide? As it has shrunk down considerably.

Comment: @Jeremie yes, see the edit.

Comment: That did it. I do have a follow up question though. I commented out everything but the `\AtBeginDocument{
 \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
  color(0ex)=(sidebar left.bg);%
  color(3ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
 }    
}` between and including the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and get the same result. What do the other pieces of code in that section do if the result appears the same without them?

Comment: If I comment the `\usebeamercolor{...}` I get "Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `sidebar left.bg'. \begin{document}", I am on TeXLive 2015. Not sure why you do not get this error?

Comment: I'm getting a warning about a missing font shape, but...ah, yes, there it is. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help!